# How to see if cells contain multiple substrings

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, match, textjoin

In Google Sheets (or Excel), I need to see if a column contains both of 2 substrings within 2 columns. For example:

Column 1 might have:

- matt@gmail.com
- matt@yahoo.com
- doug@gmail.com
- gmail@matt.com

Column 2 is 1 list of substrings:

- Row 1: matt
- Row 2: doug
- Row 3: andrew

Column 3 is another list of substrings:

- Row 1: gmail
- Row 2: aol
- Row 3: gmail

So Column 2 & 3 combined would be:

- matt & gmail
- doug & aol
- andrew & gmail

I need to get Column 1 values that contain BOTH values in the *same* row of column 2 & 3, but in any order. So this would return TRUE for these and nothing else:

- matt@gmail.com
- gmail@matt.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:A, 
 MATCH(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C:C)), C:C, 0)=
 MATCH(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, D:D)), D:D, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I looks like it works, but it's acting weird & only doing like 55 at a time. I'll play around with it though now that I have a basic function for it working. Thanks again!